# Complex number manipulation

Tags: complex-numbers

Considering that we have $w = e^z$ how can we be convinced that 
$z=\log\left(r\right) + i\theta$ ?
is there a way to get to this without using $w=re^\left(i\theta \right)$?

Comment: I mean... How are you defining $r$ and $\theta$ in that case? Also, $z = \log r + i(\theta + 2\pi)$ works just as well, so be careful.

Comment: those are the parameters of the polar form. but not the $re^\left(itheta\right)$

Comment: @math_student So it sounds like what you really want to prove is that a complex number is $r\exp i\theta$ in terms of its polar coordinates. We cannot in fact compute $z$ from $e^z$, because $e^z=e^{z+2\pi i}$. (Another way to describe this is to say that $\ln w$ has muitiple branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy to assume that $w = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ (since that's polar form), then we might proceed as follows. Let $z = x + iy$ with $x, y \in \mathbb R$. Then $e^z = e^{x + iy} = e^x(\cos y + i \sin y)$ by definition of the complex exponential. Then by equating real and imaginary parts of $e^z$ and $w$, we get
\begin{align*}
 r\cos \theta &= e^x \cos y \\
 r\sin \theta &= e^x \sin y
\end{align*}
Squaring and adding these together, $r^2 = e^{2x}$, so $e^x = \pm r$. If $x$ is to be real, then $e^x$ should be positive, so take $e^x = r \implies x = \log r$. Then we can cancel the $e^x$s, getting
\begin{align*}
 \cos \theta &= \cos y \\
 \sin \theta &= \sin y
\end{align*}
You can check if you want that the only possible solutions to this are $y = \theta + 2\pi n$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$. Therefore,
$w = \log r + i(\theta + 2\pi n)$ (which is the only thing we can deduce from $w = e^z$, since for example $e^{i\pi} = e^{3i\pi}$.)

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$z=\ln w = \ln (re^{i\theta} )=\ln r + \ln e^{i\theta}=\ln r + {i\theta }$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $w$ in polar coordinates:  $w = r e^{i \theta}$, where $r = |w|$ and $\theta = \arg w$.
Now consider this other complex number, $z = \log r + i\theta$.  What is $e^z$ ?   Compute
$$
e^{z}= e^{\log r + i\theta} = e^{\log r}\;e^{i\theta} = r e^{i\theta} = w .
$$

**Note**
This fails when $w=0$ so $r=0$ and $\log r$ is undefined.  Zero does not belong to the range of the complex exponential function.

Comment: is it possible without assuming the polar form first?